# Duplicating a division with child elements and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to stack overflow so sorry if I don't articulate my problems well or show my code properly. working on a homework assignment where I have to create a game like the classic mastermind one. I have designed the game board and have created a 'round 1' division with toggling color buttons, submit button, and even calls up the proper result image (combination of white & black dots as img png).

My js code for duplicating the rounds is below. my problem is duplicating the round and all the functionality 9 more times. I would like to disable the toggle color buttons of a round once it is submitted and I would need to assign a new id to both the title of the round as well as the div where the result image would appear (since that changes with each new guess). But no matter what I try (generate all the code as string and append to body) the best I can get is 10 rounds but only functionality with round 1. All classes and Ids are same so the same event handlers and jQuery links should apply, yes?

Any-who, any help or suggestion is appreciated (thanks).

script code for creating rounds-

```
 const nextRound = '
<div id="Round" class="level">
  <h3 class="title"></h3>
  <div class="buttondisplay">
    <a id="boxa" class="button" class="active"></a>
    <a id="boxb" class="button" class="active"></a>
    <a id="boxc" class="button" class="active"></a>
    <a id="boxd" class="button" class="active"></a>
  </div><a id="submit" class="submitter">SUBMIT</a>
  <div id="res1" class="results"></div>
</div>'; 

const buildRounds = () => { for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){ 
    $('#Gameboard').append(nextRound); }
}
```

The elements I would want to apply new ids are the `boxa`, `boxb`, `boxc`, and `boxd`, as well as the 'submit' and `res1` (for resultsimage.png). Have been banging my head trying to make this work. Any help would be great. Or if you need more of the code, I can provide.

Thanks!

Rick

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

ids must be unique per page. You have a total of 6 different ids and each of those ids has 10 duplicates. jQuery/JavaScript will expect only one `#Round` or it expects one `#boxc` so once it finds an id it stops there and all the other duplicates are ignored or worse not entirely ignored. Basically when you have more than one element sharing an id, you will most likely get undesirable results if any at all. So you must make each id unique and a common way to do that is to assign a number to each id during a loop (i.e. `"Round"+i`)

BTW an element cannot have any duplicate attributes as well. So

> ```
> <a id="boxd" class="button" class="active"></a>
> ```

is invalid and most likely the `class='button'` will be overwritten by `class='active'`. For multiple classes on a single element the syntax is:

> ```
>  <a id="boxd" class="button active"></a>
> ```

**Details are commented in demo**

**Verify that all ids are unique by inspecting the page with DevTools.**

> #### `Added Demo 2 which uses String Literals instead of Template Literals. IE does not support` [Template Literals](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template) `hence Demo 2.`

### Demo 1 -- **Using Template Literals**

```js
// Pass a number of rounds (i.e. 'qty')
function buildRounds(qty) {

  /* Declare 'i' with 'let' limits i to only what
  || applies within the scope of the 'for' loop.
  || This limit helps 'i' to increment properly
  || without the influence of references outside
  || of the loop.
  */
  for (let i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {

    /* Use ES6 Template Literals* for complex strings
    || by wrapping the whole string with backticks `.
    || What is seen in code is literally rendered so 
    || new lines are NOT ignored and escaping quotes
    || like this: `\'`or `\"` is not needed.
    || ${variable} is an interpolation of a value
    || inserted into the string. Note that the value 'i'
    || will be different on each loop therefore 
    || ensuring unique ids.
    */
    const nextRound = `
<div id="round${i}" class="level"> 
  <h3 class="title">Round ${i}</h3>
  <div class="buttonDisplay">
    <a id="boxA${i}" class="button">A</a>
    <a id="boxB${i}" class="button">B</a>
    <a id="boxC${i}" class="button">C</a> 
    <a id="boxD${i}" class="button">D</a>
  </div>
  <a id="submit${i}" class="submitter">SUBMIT</a>
  <div id="result${i}" class="results"></div>
</div>
`;
    $('#gameBoard').append(nextRound);
  }

  /* Added function will toggle the '.active' class on/off
  || on each clicked '.button'. I don't know exactly what
  || good a "status" class would be if on every button,
  || so I changed it so now it can be toggled by user
  */
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
}
/* Call buildRounds() and pass the number
|| of rounds desired.
*/
buildRounds(10);

/* * Template Literals are not supported by M$ browsers 
|| (i.e. IE). See Demo 2
*/
```

```css
.button,
.submitter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px ridge blue;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.active {
  border: 3px inset red;
  outline: 2px solid tomato;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main id='gameBoard'></main>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Demo 2 -- **Using `+` to concat strings.**

```js
function buildRounds(qty) {

  for (let i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {

    /* This portion of the code is modifed to the use
    || of string literals instead of template literals.
    || If IE support is needed, then use this version.
    */
    const nextRound = '<div id="round' + i + '" class ="level"><h3 class="title"> Round ' + i + ' </h3><div class="buttonDisplay"><a id="boxA' + i + '" class="button">A</a><a id="boxB' + i + '" class="button">B</a><a id="boxC' + i + '" class="button">C</a><a id="boxD' + i + '" class="button">D</a></div><a id="submit' + i + '" class="submitter">SUBMIT</a><div id="result' + i + '" class = "results"></div></div>';

    $('#gameBoard').append(nextRound);
  }

  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
}

buildRounds(10);
```

```css
.button,
.submitter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px ridge blue;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.active {
  border: 3px inset red;
  outline: 2px solid tomato;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main id='gameBoard'></main>






<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```